# Profiles for debugging multiple projects in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on a big application that consists of different modules. If I need to debug the authentication flow for instance I have to set as startup 2 projects (an API and a mocked services); but when running a let's say an integration flow, I have to set up other 3 projects.

Every time I change from one to another, I have to manually go to the Solution's properties and select the corresponding ones by going to the **Multiple startup projects** section.

[image: Multiple Startup Projects VS2019]

Is there a way to configure 'profiles' (I don't know if this would be the accurate word) to have a shortcut for this so that I can easily change from one to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SwitchStartupProject](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-141975.SwitchStartupProjectForVS2019) extension to switch between multi-project startup configurations.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, I didn't know it existed. Thank you very much!